# CustomView with Dynamic ScrollView ContentSize Autolayout called in addSubview

Tags: uiscrollview, autolayout, contentsize

I have a customView created in xib with height = 800 :

[image: customView with 800 height]

I want to call it via addSubview into the blue view as shown in the UIViewController :

[image: wantToShowHereView in UIViewController]

the problem here is I want my UIScrollView can dynamically set it's contentSize, because here I define it's height to 800 :

[image]

I read from another article that the contentSize in AutoLayout will be defined by the height of its subView, in this case the contentView. but still after I set the height to 800 the scroll is not reaching the bottom of the view (pink). how to set the autolayout then?

[image: Broken ScrollView]

here is my code in the customView :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
NSLog(@"initWithFrame");
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    [self setup];
}
return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
NSLog(@"initWithCoder");
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if(self) {
    [self setup];
}
return self;
}

- (void)setup {

[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customView" owner:self options:nil];
[self addSubview:self.view];
NSLog(@"contentSize Height :%f", self.myscrollview.contentSize.height);
NSLog(@"contentView Height :%f", self.contentView.frame.size.height);
}
```

in my ViewController.m i called it like this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

customView *customV = [[customView alloc] initWithFrame:self.wantToShowHereView.bounds];
[self.wantToShowHereView addSubview:customV];

}
```

Can someone give me direction on how I want to achieve it?
Here is my example project to make it clear for you : [AutoLayoutScrollView Example](https://github.com/xeravim/XIBAutoLayout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues.

First, you are setting the frame of `customV` to the bounds of `wantToShowHereView` -- but you're doing so in `viewDidLoad()`. That bounds will almost certainly change between `viewDidLoad()` and the time you actually see it on screen (device size, orientation, etc).

Second, `customV` is a `UIView` onto which you are adding the XIB's "root view" (which contains your scroll view) as a subview to `customV` ... but you're not setting any constraints (or other resizing behaviors) on *that* view.

Third, you're mixing relative constraints with absolute constraints (widths, heights, leading, trailing, etc), which will again cause issues when the overall frame changes... ***and*** you're explicitly setting the frame of `customV` instead of adding constraints at run-time.

You can get a start on fixing things:

Step one - remove `customV` instantiation from `viewDidLoad()`.

Step two - add the following `viewDidAppear()` method.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    customView *customV = [[customView alloc] initWithFrame:self.wantToShowHereView.bounds];
    customV.view.frame = customV.bounds;
    [self.wantToShowHereView addSubview:customV];

}
```

Doing only that *should* give you a properly scrollable view.

What you *probably* want to do, though, is keep the init in `viewDidAppear()` but add constraints there to make use of auto-layout.

Also, I'd recommend re-working the constraints on the elements in your `customView.xib` so the scrolling (the contentSize) is determined by the actual content of your scroll view, not by hard-coding a height of your `contentView`.

---

**Edit:**

Here is how your `viewDidLoad` could look (in `ViewController.m`):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    customView *customV = [[customView alloc] initWithFrame:self.wantToShowHereView.bounds];
    [self.wantToShowHereView addSubview:customV];

    customV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [customV.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.wantToShowHereView.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [customV.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.wantToShowHereView.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    [customV.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.wantToShowHereView.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [customV.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.wantToShowHereView.trailingAnchor].active = YES;

}
```

and `setup` in `customView.m`:

```
- (void)setup {

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customView" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.view];

    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.view.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.view.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.view.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.trailingAnchor].active = YES;

    NSLog(@"contentSize Height :%f", self.myscrollview.contentSize.height);
    NSLog(@"contentView Height :%f", self.contentView.frame.size.height);

}
```

Comment: Hi @DonMag, thank you for the pointer. but I am still a little bit confused. in viewDidAppear I should add constraint to customV right? so when adding customV to wantToShowHereView there will be autolayout there  right?

Comment: the constraint will be constraint between customV and wantToShowHereView?

Comment: Thanks its work! sorry for not updating to you. thank you